# How to Add Dynamic Parameter to Power Query (Excel)

Tags: sql, excel, powerquery

I have Stored procedure  named "Operation" .I connect it to  Power Query (excel).I'm not sure if this is possible but want to run it with dynamic parameter that the user is adding from sheet .Is this possible ?

Comment: Show the code you have for calling the stored procedure. It is not easy to inject variables into SQL queries, for security reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like perhaps you want to use the values stored in a named range within a powerquery

give the input cell (such as A1) a range name, like **XVariable** in excel

Then in powerquery, in home ... advanced editor ... add a formula that refers to that range name, similar to this:

```
XVar = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="XVariable"]}[Content]{0}[Column1],
```

Change any hard coded powerquery code to use the variable, such as here, where a comparison is made to contents of range **XVariable** that is now in **XVar**

```
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"PriorStep", "Test", each if [x] < XVar then 1 else 0)
```

Comment: Only, the OP doesn't want to use the variable in a PQ column, it should be passed on as a parameter to a SQL queyr stored procedure.

Comment: Ita a variable stored in an excel ranged name not a PQ column, but google for SQL variable, there are a million answers